# ¿Como puedo crear múltiples elementos script?

Tags: javascript, html

Recientemente estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto web, y se me has solicitado buscar una alternativa con el uso del `document.write`, ya que este considerado como mala practica y afecta al rendimiento de la página, este es utilizado dentro de un archivo js de la siguiente manera:

```
document.write('<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/parallax.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.countTo.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/pace.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="assets/js/plugins/additional-methods.min.js"></script>');
```

Intenté utilizar `document.createElement` de la siguiente manera:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/parallax.min.js';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/jquery.countTo.min.js';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/jquery.inview.min.jss';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/pace.min.js';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js';
script.src = 'assets/js/plugins/additional-methods.min.js';
document.body.append(script);

console.log([...document.body.querySelectorAll('script[src]')]);
```

Pero no sé si eso estaría realmente bueno.
¿Me podría ayudar a encontrar la solución?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). Si aún tenes alguna duda, también podes revisar [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Un tag `script` solo puede tener un `src`.
En tu código lo que estas haciendo es sobre escribir el `src` cada vez que le asignas uno nuevo.

#### Solución:

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Crear un arreglo con las URL de los `scripts`
- Iterar arreglo y crear los `scripts` a medida que lo recorremos.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
// Creamos un arreglo con los links
let scripts = [
  'assets/js/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js',
  'assets/js/plugins/parallax.min.js',
  'assets/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
  'assets/js/plugins/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js',
  'assets/js/plugins/jquery.countTo.min.js',
  'assets/js/plugins/jquery.inview.min.jss',
  'assets/js/plugins/pace.min.js',
  'assets/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js',
  'assets/js/plugins/additional-methods.min.js'
];
// Iteramos/recorremos el arreglo para crear cada unos de los scripts
scripts.forEach(src => {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  document.body.append(script);
})


console.log([...document.body.querySelectorAll('script[src]')]);
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu segundo bloque de código, estas reasignando el `sr` del `<script>`, mas no creando uno nuevo por cada vez que lo reasignas

Como trabajas con tantos scripts, se almacenará mucho código si usas `createElement`, puedes simplemente aumentarle el contenido al `innerHTML` de `<body>`

```js
document.body.innerHTML += `
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/parallax.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.countTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plugins/additional-methods.min.js"></script>`;

console.log(document.body.querySelectorAll('script[src]'));
```

Comment: Hacerlo así puede ser "costos", ya que el navegador tiene que re-renderizar todo el árbol del DOM para agregar el nuevo `HTML`.